# NSURL object value is null

Tags: ios, url

I am generating a URL as given by string parameters but url gives null value.
For generating URL I have implemented the following code .

```
 NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] init];
 NSString *strURL = @"ftp://Administrat:ABC(R%-@TRDOP@xx.xx.xx.xx/arrows.png";
 url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithString:strURL]];
 NSLog(@"URL :: %@",url);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the special characters in the url query string.

Use:

```
NSString *strURL = @"ftp://www.jerox.com/Administrator:@123@TRDOP@%$/arrows.png";
strURL =[strURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:strURL];
NSLog(@"URL :: %@",url);
```

Also I need to mention some mistakes in your code:

- No need to allocate and init the NSURL object, because you are again assigning another object to that pointer
- No need of using `stringWithString:` there

Comment: HI Midhun, Please see my updated question I have been facing problem in that URL string.Thanks.

Comment: @JekilPatel: What is the issue ? I'm getting the NSURL properly.

Comment: Thanks Midhun for your reply.The issue is I got the warning at this line - "NSString *strURL = @"ftp://Administrat:ABC(R%-@TRDOP@xx.xx.xx.xx/arrows.png";". and warning is-"more % conversions than data argument" and image is not being displayed.

Comment: @JekilPatel: I'm not getting the warning, if i use like above. The only time I got the issue was when I used : `NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Administrat:ABC(R%-@TRDOP@xx.xx.xx.xx/arrows.png"];`

Comment: Thanks Midhun for your reply, yes exactlly i am getting the same issue over here so what would be the solution for that?

Comment: @JekilPatel: ok, use like: `NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Administrat:ABC(R%%-@TRDOP@xx.xx.xx.xx/arrows.png"];`

Comment: Thanks Midhun it works. now recently I faced an issue that while I am sending that value by URL at that time the image has not been set on my image view.

Comment: should be noted that `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` is depreciated in iOS9. Should now use:
`strURL = [strURL stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet]];`

Answer (score 1):

Make use of the following code.

```
NSString *sURL = @"ftp://www.jerox.com/Administrator:@123@TRDOP@%$/arrows.png";
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[sURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSLog(@"URL :: %@",url);
```

Comment: Thanks vinayak. It works but the problem is it appends " -- file://localhost/" at the end of the url.How could i remove it?

Answer (score 0):

From your posted code sample, here is the problem:

```
 NSString *strURL = @"ftp://Administrat:ABC(R%-@TRDOP@xx.xx.xx.xx/arrows.png";
```

Look carefully at the authority component (username, password and host). An `@` symbol is used in URLs to separate username & password from the host. Because your password contains an `@` character, it must be percent escaped. The percent encoding of `@` is `%40`, giving you instead the code:

```
 NSString *strURL = @"ftp://Administrat:ABC(R%-%40TRDOP@xx.xx.xx.xx/arrows.png";
```

You really ought to be escaping other URL-specific characters in there too, like the lone `%` symbol.